# Express.js, Node.js Jade - Following the expressjs.com tutorials, and getting errors

Tags: node.js, pug, express

Well I'm trying to get into Node.js / Express.js - however I've been having a few issue going through the screencast, the first issue, now resolved, was pretty obvious when it was spotted ([Express.js, Node.js Jade vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843850/express-js-node-js-jade-vim)).

However, I'm now getting the following errors:

```
Express
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

    * at Object.Function (unknown source)
    * at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/jade/0.10.6/package/lib/jade.js:230:10)
    * at ServerResponse._render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/view.js:368:22)
    * at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/view.js:234:17)
    * at Object. (/home/duncan/helloExpress/app.js:46:7)
    * at nextMiddleware (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/router/index.js:139:34)
    * at param (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/router/index.js:147:16)
    * at pass (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/router/index.js:155:10)
    * at Object.router [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.3.2/package/lib/router/index.js:161:6)
    * at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.4.0/package/lib/http.js:204:15)
```

My app.js code is as follows:
Declare the users array of object

```
var users = [
    { name: 'Duncan',   email: 'duncan@email.com'},
    { name: 'Bob',  email: 'bob@email.com'}
];
```

and...
the bit that calls and renders the new users.jade

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
  res.render('users', {
        users: users
  });

});
```

I don't know if I'm just being blind today, but I would really like to get this example working.

NB. app.js 46:7 is the 'res.render' char 7 is the . between res and render. - from the error message.

The users.jade file is as follows:

```
h1 Users
ul#users
    -   each user in users
    li= user.name
```

If I get rid of the:
user in users
and li= user.name

it renders the page, as soon as I add them, it gives me the above error message, and says there is something wrong with res.render('users' - on the dot (46:7).

PS. I'm following the second tutorial on here: http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html

My indentation:

```
[indent] - [indent] each user in users
[indent][indent] li= [indent] user.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indent the `li= user.name` another level down from the each statement.

This should work:

```
h1 Users
ul#users
  - each user in users
    li= user.name
```

Comment: I got it working, at first I thought I hadn't but then I realised I'd  made some other changes to try and get it working, and thus breaking it at the same time.  

So basically Jade requires very exact indentation, something I need to keep in mind.

Thanks mikl. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the tradeoff with Jade and similar syntaxes. You don't have to type delimiters like <>[]{}() or similar, but you have to be very exact with the indentation for your code to be parsed correctly. Everything indented after the each block is part of the loop, so in your case it could not find an indented block, and complained about the empty loop :)

Comment: There's a pretty good [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/Readme.md) as well as a folder full of [examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/master/examples) that I tend to refer to :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because in my layout.jade

I had:

```
html(class="no-js" lang="en")
```

AND CLEARLY THAT ^^^ SPOT RIGHT THERE IS MISSING A COMMA!!!!
Jade is great and all, but wow that error message is bad for beginners.

Should have been:

```
html(class="no-js", lang="en")
```